# R: delete rows that have two columns with the same first digit

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to delete rows whose county fips codes start with the same number.

```
# What I have ----

x.dist = data.frame(county1=c(8001,8001,8001),
                    mi_to=c(10:12),
                    county2=c(8005,34502,8007))
> x.dist
  county1 mi_to county2
1    8001    10    8005
2    8001    11   34502
3    8001    12    8007

# What I want ----

  county1 mi_to county2
2    8001    11   34502
```

In the original df, county1 and county2 both start with 8 in rows 1 and 3. I want the first digit in each column to differ so I'm left with row 2. How do I do this?

I tried this, but absolutely nothing happened.

```
w.dist = x.dist %>%   
filter(str_sub(county1, start= 1) != (str_sub(county2, start= 1)))
```

Comment: Try `x.dist %>% filter(str_extract(county1, "^.") != str_extract(county2, "^."))`.

Comment: @MartinGal What does the "^." do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `str_sub()` with the default `end` parameter, which takes you to the end of the string:. Try this:

```
x.dist %>% filter(str_sub(county1,1,1)!=str_sub(county2,1,1))
```

Comment: Yay! This also worked! Would you mind explaining the 1,1 at the end?

Comment: `str_sub()` takes three arguments: the string from which to extract a substring, the start , and the end. So `str_sub(county1,1,1)` means extract the substring of county1, starting at the first character and ending at the first character

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option with `substr` and `subset`

```
subset(x.dist, substr(county1, 1, 2) != substr(county2, 1, 2))
  county1 mi_to county2
2    8001    11   34502
```